# Flutter type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' after navigating

Tags: flutter, navigation, multiple-screens

I have 4 screens (home, Excursion, Spa, detail) and I want to navigate from multiple to one detailed screen (from home, Excursion, Spa to detail) it work fine at first but after it give me: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' Error, if I navigate from the "Excursion" or "Spa" page to the "Detail" page. but it work fine if I navigate from the home the detail screen.
this is the Home screen

```dart
    Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: ()=>Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Detail',arguments:{
                'previousScreenData':dataList_home[index],
              }
              ),
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                      children:<Widget>[
                        Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(dataList_home[index]["PHOTO"]),
                          height: 250,
                          fit:BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Column(
                            children:<Widget>[
                              Text(
                                dataList_home[index]["LIBELLE"],
                              ),

                            ]

                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Column(
                            children:<Widget>[
                              Text(
                                dataList_home[index]["PRICE_AD"],
                              ),

                            ]

                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children:<Widget>[
                            for ( var i in iconList ) Row(

                                children:<Widget>[
                                  FaIcon(iconMapping [i.toString()] ?? FontAwesomeIcons.question,),


                                ]
                            ),

                          ],

                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

this is the Spa screen

```dart
    Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: ()=>Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Detail',arguments:{
                'previousScreenData':dataList_spa[index],
              }),
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                      children:<Widget>[
                        Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(dataList_spa[index]["PHOTO"]),
                          height: 250,
                          fit:BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Column(
                            children:<Widget>[
                              Text(
                                dataList_spa[index]["LIBELLE"],
                              ),

                            ]

                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Column(
                            children:<Widget>[
                              Text(
                                dataList_spa[index]["PRICE_AD"],
                              ),

                            ]

                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children:<Widget>[
                            for ( var i in iconList ) Row(

                                children:<Widget>[
                                  FaIcon(iconMapping [i.toString()] ?? FontAwesomeIcons.question),


                                ]
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                      ]
                  ),

                ),
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

This is the Detail Screen

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dataMap=ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;//We recieve the data as a Map from the home screen
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NizdG.jpg
```

Comment: Did you try to check in your Excursioen screen if the string has value in it? ... It seems in the Excursioen screen you are passing a null string to the Spa screen.

Comment: Yes I printed it and the value exist